# Не могу получить последний id

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код проверяет последний id в таблице.

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
    $db   = '';
    $user = '';
    $pass = ';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT MAX(id) FROM users');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
?>
```

Но echo ничего не выводит.
error log выводит

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in /home/fun/test.php on line 17

Comment: SELECT MAX(id) **AS id** FROM users. Поле должно иметь имя...

Comment: @Akina точно, спасибо. Давайте ответ.

Comment: *Давайте ответ.* Да нет тут материала на ответ... Кстати, при отсутствии имени поле получает имя, равное самому выражению. Т.е. можно было в начальном коде получить значение, используя ``echo $row['MAX(id)'];`` или ``echo $row['`MAX(id)`'];`` (не знаю как правильно в PHP, пробовать надо...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
    $db   = '';
    $user = '';
    $pass = ';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM users');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
?>
```